# React app failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js

I deploy react app on my server it work fine on localhost but when I try to use it on my server I got

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     shayankh.me/graphql

my root location on server is /var/www/html/

`
this is my server.js

```
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { autoIndex: false })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

// Initializes application
const app = express();

const corsOtions = {
  origin: "https://shayankh.me",
  Credential: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOtions));

// Set up JWT authentication middleware
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers["authorization"];
  if (token !== "null") {
    try {
      const currentUser = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
      req.currentUser = currentUser;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  next();
});

//Create GraphiQL Application
app.use("/graphiql", graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: "/graphql" }));

// Connect Schemas with  GraphQL
app.use(
  "./graphql",
  bodyParser.json(),
  graphqlExpress(({ currentUser }) => ({
    schema,
    context: {
      CarDetails,
      User,
      currentUser,
    },
  }))
);

app.use(express.static('public'));
express.static(path_join(__dirname, '../client/build'))
app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
 });

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname , "public", "index.html"))
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

and index.js

```
  uri: "/graphql",
  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: "include",
  },
  request: (operation) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        authorization: token,
      },
    });
  },
  onError: ({ networkError }) => {
    if (networkError) {
      console.log("Network Error", networkError);
    }
  },
});

const Root = ({ refetch, session }) => (
  <Router>
    <Fragment>
      <Navbar session={session} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
        <Route path="/signin" render={() => <Signin refetch={refetch} />} />
        <Route path="/signup" render={() => <Signup refetch={refetch} />} />
        <Route
          path="/carDetail/add"
          render={() => <AddCar session={session} />}
        />
        <Route path="/carDetails/:_id" component={CarDetailPage} />
        <Route path="/profile" render={() => <Profile session={session} />} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  </Router>
);

const RootWithSession = withSession(Root);

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <RootWithSession />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I don't know what and where is my problem.
Is there any chance that the problem is that my app cant find GraphQL because of root location of server?
Also I'm using nginx on my server.

Comment: what do these two lines do...?  app.use(express.static('public')); **followed by** express.static(path_join(__dirname, '../client/build'))

Comment: and what about these two...? app.use(cors(corsOtions)); **followed by** app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
 });

Comment: and what about this....app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname , "public", "index.html"))
}); how are you supposed to handle the graphql endpoint? **please** debug your code section by section and try to understand what your app does when the server file runs

Comment: @rags2riches those to line are for add build folder on local client i think and I use cors to give access to crosover site can access on backend and front end

Comment: and do they work as you want...?

Comment: @rags2riches on my localhost yes,they work fine

Answer (score 0):

You have . in api, try below code

```
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  bodyParser.json(),
  graphqlExpress(({ currentUser }) => ({
    schema,
    context: {
      CarDetails,
      User,
      currentUser,
    },
  }))
);
```

Comment: You removed . from "./graphql" ? If not then try removing it.

Comment: no it doeant wokr with . without . any thing 
I think It's has something with ports but not sure